# Let $A,B \in (X \to X)$ be linear operations such that $A^2=B^2$ and $ KerA \cap KerB= {\{0}\}$. Show that

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A,B \in (X \to X)$ such that $A^2=B^2$ and $ KerA \cap KerB= {\{0}\}$. Show that

$a) A(\mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rB) \subseteq \mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rA$

$b) \ \mathrm d\mathrm i \mathrm mA(\mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rB)=\mathrm d\mathrm i\mathrm m(\mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm r B) $

$c) \ \mathrm d\mathrm i\mathrm m(\mathrm I\mathrm mA)=\mathrm d\mathrm i\mathrm m(\mathrm I\mathrm mB) $

Can somebody help me with this problem? I was able to show the problem in $a)$.This is what I did

Let $y \in  A(\mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rB)$ be an arbitrary element. This implies that there exists $x \in \mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rB$ such that $A(x)=y$

From $x \in \mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rB \Rightarrow B(x)=0 \Rightarrow B^2(x)=0 \Rightarrow A^2(x)=B^2(x)=0 $

$\Rightarrow A(A(x))=0 \Rightarrow A(y)=0 \Rightarrow y \in \mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rA $

So we have $A(\mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rB) \subseteq \mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rA$

But I'm stuck in the problems in $b)$ and $c)$. I tried using the fact that $\mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rB \subseteq \mathrm K\mathrm e\mathrm rB^2$ and $\mathrm I \mathrm mB^2 \subseteq \mathrm I \mathrm mB$ but I didn't get anywhere. I would really appreciate some help

Comment: In b) what does $def(B)$ mean?

Comment: $defB=dim(KerB)$

Comment: For b), show that if two elements of the kernel of $B$ are linearly independent, then when you hit them with $A$ the results are still linearly independent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think I can show that unless I know that $KerB={\{0\}}$ or if the two elements belong also in $KerA$ because then they would be also in the intersection which means that their linear combination is 0, this implies the linear independence

Comment: Can you prove that if $Ax$ and $Ay$ are not linearly independent then some linear combination of $x$ and $y$ is in the kernel of $A$?

Comment: Oh my God how did I miss that? Thank you very much. Post it as an answer so I can select it. Do you have any idea about the $c)$

Comment: About c) is it enough to prove that $defA=defB$ since $rangA+defA=dimX=rangB+defB$ ?

Comment: @J.Dane $rang(A)$ means the image of $A$ or the dimension of image of $A$?

Comment: $rangA=dim(ImA)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b) we can use that $\text{ker}(A)\cap\text{ker}(B)=\{0\}$. Hence for all non-zero $x\in\ker(B)$ we find that $Ax\neq0$. So 
$$\dim\text{ker}(B)=\dim A(\text{ker}(B))+\dim\text{ker}(A|_{\text{ker}(B)})=\dim A(\text{ker}(B)).\quad(1)$$

For c) we can use that
$$\dim(X)=\dim(\text{ker}(A))+\dim(\text{im}(A))=\dim(\text{ker}(B))+\dim(\text{im}(B)).\quad(2)$$
From a) and b) we know that
$$\dim(\text{ker}(B))=\dim(A(\text{ker}(B))\leq\dim(\text{ker}(A))$$
and as $A$ and $B$ are interchangeable we also have 
$$\dim(\text{ker}(A))=\dim(B(\text{ker}(A))\leq\dim(\text{ker}(B)).$$
Thus $\dim(\text{ker}(A))=\dim(\text{ker}(B))$ and using $(2)$ gives us that $\dim(\text{im}(A))=\dim(\text{im}(B))$.

Comment: That's what I thought doing for c). But can you explain $(1)$? I don't understand it

Comment: I noticed I labelled the wrong equation, but basically what I'm doing in (1) is the same thing I'm doing in (2), I am writing the dimension of the entire space, ker$(B)$ as the sum of the dimension of the image of an operator and the dimension of the kernel of the operator $A|_{\text{ker}(B)}$.